# make uinput device evdev

Tags: drivers

I'm in the process of writing a driver for a game controller. I successfully read data into a C++ program from the hardware and used `uinput` to make a device. However, that device is `/dev/input/js0` and most modern games use the `evdev` approach `/dev/input/eventN`.

How can I achieve this?

I either need to somehow convert the `uinput` device into an `evdev` device or create the `evdev` from scratch. I looked into `libevdev`, but it only seems to operate on existing `evdev` devices.